# Sending formatted Email Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

```
MailAddress to = new MailAddress(emailTo, emailToName);
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
message.Subject = dtlSubscribe.Rows[i]["NewsLetter_Title"].ToString().Trim();
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
string msgBody = "<html><body>" + dtlSubscribe.Rows[i]["NewsLetter_Body"].ToString().Trim() + "</body></html>";
Console.WriteLine(msgBody);
message.Body = msgBody;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(SMTPServer, 25);
client.Send(message);
message.Dispose();
```

That's how I write my email in code.

in `msgBody`, I put `<html><body>` then place the record retrieved from database.

This is what I get.

```
<ol> <li>Number1</li> <li>Number2</li> <li><p>Number3</p> </li> </ol> <p><a title="/NHGD/assets/0/71/90/92/b834e617-473d-49e8-beb1-ecade3afdd2f.jpg" onkeypress="this.onclick();" onclick="try{window.open('/NHGD/assets/0/71/90/92/b834e617-473d-49e8-beb1-ecade3afdd2f.jpg', 'MyImage', 'resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, width=790, height=580')}catch(e){};return false;" href="#"><img title="DiagnosticsService1" border="0" alt="DiagnosticsService1" src="/NHGD/assets/0/71/90/92/thumb_b834e617-473d-49e8-beb1-ecade3afdd2f.jpg" /></a></p> <p> </p> <p>End<br /></p>
```

Apart from `<html><body>` which I put in myself.. my record from database is not formatted.

So, I debug a bit.. and found this..

```
<html><body>&lt;ol&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Number1&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Number2&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;Number3&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ol&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;a title=&quot;/NHGD/assets/0/71/90/92/b834e617-473d-49e8-beb1-ecade
3afdd2f.jpg&quot; onkeypress=&quot;this.onclick();&quot; onclick=&quot;try{windo
w.open('/NHGD/assets/0/71/90/92/b834e617-473d-49e8-beb1-ecade3afdd2f.jpg', 'MyIm
age', 'resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, width=790, height=580')}catch(e){};return
false;&quot; href=&quot;#&quot;&gt;&lt;img title=&quot;DiagnosticsService1&quot;
 border=&quot;0&quot; alt=&quot;DiagnosticsService1&quot; src=&quot;/NHGD/assets
/0/71/90/92/thumb_b834e617-473d-49e8-beb1-ecade3afdd2f.jpg&quot; /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;End&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</body></html>
<html><body>&lt;ol&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Number1&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Number2&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;&lt;p&gt;Number3&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ol&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;a title=&quot;/NHGD/assets/0/71/90/92/b834e617-473d-49e8-beb1-ecade
3afdd2f.jpg&quot; onkeypress=&quot;this.onclick();&quot; onclick=&quot;try{windo
w.open('/NHGD/assets/0/71/90/92/b834e617-473d-49e8-beb1-ecade3afdd2f.jpg', 'MyIm
age', 'resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, width=790, height=580')}catch(e){};return
false;&quot; href=&quot;#&quot;&gt;&lt;img title=&quot;DiagnosticsService1&quot;
 border=&quot;0&quot; alt=&quot;DiagnosticsService1&quot; src=&quot;/NHGD/assets
/0/71/90/92/thumb_b834e617-473d-49e8-beb1-ecade3afdd2f.jpg&quot; /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;End&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</body></html>
```

Found out that when it is stored into database, all the special characters have been changed into that.

Which is why there is no error while saving into database.

Now, my question is how to change them back to their original characters??

So that, it will be formatted properly..

Thanks a lot..

Comment: What does `Server.HtmlDecode` do for your text, check out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes this is true you can not save html data to database. you must convert your string to html encoded string using `Server.HtmlEncode` to avoid page validation error etc..

and if you are accessing your Html Encoded data from datatables then use `Server.HtmlDecode`().

Follow these for more information:

Server.HtmlEncode: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525347%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Server.HtmlDecode: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwzhtkke.aspx

```
String msgBody = "<html><body>" + Server.HtmlDecode(dtlSubscribe.Rows[i]["NewsLetter_Body"].ToString().Trim()) + "</body></html>";
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HttpUtility HtmlDecode/HtmlEncode` method to achive what you needed.

using System.Web;

var encoded = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(unencoded);

Also, there is an interesting article [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/htmlencodingcsharp.aspx)

Alternately

```
public static string CustomHtmlEncode(string value) 
{    
   char[] chars = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(YourDbString).ToCharArray(); 
   StringBuilder encodedValue = new StringBuilder(); 
   foreach(char c in chars) 
   { 
      if ((int)c > 127) // above normal ASCII 
         encodedValue.Append("&#" + (int)c + ";"); 
      else 
         encodedValue.Append(c); 
   } 
   return encodedValue.ToString(); 
}
```